# Swift Compiler Error when using Generics and nested functions, Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, swift3

The following code is causing an error when compiled with Swift 3 and Xcode 8:

```
import Foundation

public typealias IntCompletion = (Int) -> Void
public typealias FetchIntBlock = (IntCompletion) -> Void

class ATSwiftTest<T: NSURL>: NSObject {

    var fetchIntBlock: FetchIntBlock

    override init() {
        fetchIntBlock = { (aFunc) in }

        super.init()
    }
}
```

By the process of elimination I was able to figure out that the problem is caused by the nested function declaration.

`var fetchIntBlock: FetchIntBlock`

The code crashes a Playground compiler as well.

Is there any way of tricking the compiler?

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that if I make the `fetchIntBlock` var private the code compiles just fine.

It would still be nice for the var to be public.